# What does "rise to low expectations" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used this link but it didn't help: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rise-to?q=rise+to

"No one **rises to low expectations**. Having high expectations of each and every student and then providing the necessary support needed to achieve that level seem key to all students achieving to their best ability. As Rosenthal and Jacobson noted, “when teachers expected that certain children would show greater intellectual development, those children did show greater intellectual development”."

Source:https://www.theguardian.com/teacher-network/2017/nov/10/what-every-teacher-should-know-about-expectations

Answer (score 1):

It is a form of wordplay.  We cannot "rise" to something which is "low", since rise implies upward movement.  "High performance" means "excelling" and "low performance" means "failing, or doing poorly". The underlying metaphor of high/low is a standard graphical depiction in which upper positions on a chart show desirable results and lower positions show undesirable results.

When teachers expect children to show poor intellectual development, when the teachers' expectations for those students are "low", those children fulfill the expectations of the teachers and they do not develop well. The contrary was also found to be true:

> ... when teachers expected that certain children would show greater
>   intellectual development, those children did show greater intellectual
>   development.